# What happend with Google search?

Tags: search, google-search

Tried to search for my favorite character when I was just shocked with the change.
Can someone provide more details?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> Personal is a new option of Google Search that is not integrated
>   directly in the algorithm that determines which search results are
>   returned to users when they run searches on Google.
>
> It is a new option under the more link instead which you can load.
>   Please note that personal is only an option there if you are signed in
>   to a Google account, and that the new feature won't work yet for
>   Google Apps customers.

more info [at ghacks site](https://www.ghacks.net/2017/05/28/google-search-gets-personal-option/)